# AVD Manager can't find tools\android.bat even though it's there

Tags: java, android, windows, android-virtual-device, adk

I've researched this on the internet so much and nothing I find is helping me out.  I got the SDK manager to run, but when I try to run the Adroid AVD Manager, it doesn't run!!!!! Why?

It says, word for word, 
"Failed to execute tools\android.bat:
The system cannot find the file specified."

Why can it not find a file that is clearly where it is looking?

PS I'm running windows 8, installed the latest version of the ADK.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The latest SDK has AVD Manager in the SDK Manager itself. Open SDK Manager -> Tools -> Manage AVDs

Answer (score 7):

I was getting the same error and solved it by going to the tools folder (up one level in my case) and then running the android.bat file.
This then runs the SDK Manager and then follow Samarth Jain's answer above.

Comment: also you should run as Administrator

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the sdk/add-ons folder.  I created that and SDK and AVD Managers both worked correctly

Answer (score 1):

I just copied **sdk manager.exe** and **avd manager.exe** from **..sdk\tools\lib** to **..sdk**

Answer (score 0):

You may not have the correct permission level to run the program.

Try doing the following:

- Right click
- Run as administrator

Answer (score 0):

The beat and working way to solve this problem is to download the ARM EABI v7a system image for your respective API level and also the Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator(HAXM installer). After that you can run the AVD manager from the SDK manager and now select the ARM system image in the CPU section and now thw OK button will work. It worked for me and hope will work for you.