# Android SDK not working

Tags: android, sdk, swt, environment-variables, android-sdk-2.3

The Android SDK doesn't open so i tried to open `Android.bat` to see the errors and  I get this Error:

> The system cannot find the file specified. 
>   The system cannot find the file specified. 
>   The system cannot find the file specified. 
>   The system cannot find the file specified. 
>   Error: Could not find or load main class com.android.sdkmanager.Main 
>   Press any key to continue . . .

Here is my Environment Variables:

> ANDROID_SWT: C:\adt-bundle-windows-x86\sdk\tools\lib\x86. 
>   JAVA_HOME: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25. 
>  JDK_HOME:
>   C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25. 
>  PATH:(Sorted that it will be
>   Readable)
>
> `C:\Python33\;`
>  `%SystemRoot%\system32;`
>  `%SystemRoot%;`
>   `%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;`
>   `%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;`
>  `C:\Program
>   Files\Microsoft Network Monitor 3\;`
>   `C:\adt-bundle-windows-x86\sdk\platform-tools;`
>   `C:\adt-bundle-windows-x86\sdk\tools;C:\PHP;`
>  `C:\Program
>   Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;`
>  `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\110\Tools\Binn\;`
>  `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   11.0\VC\bin;`
>  `C:\Program Files\OpenVPN\bin.`

I searched the whole web and i couldn't find any answer, i would like if you will help me to fix it. 
Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [AVD Manager can't find tools\android.bat even though it's there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16753240/avd-manager-cant-find-tools-android-bat-even-though-its-there)

Comment: but i can't open the SDK Manager...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taken from the possibly duplicated thread:

> The latest SDK has AVD Manager in the SDK Manager itself. Open SDK
>   Manager -> Tools -> Manage AVDs

Comment: Try to re-deploy maybe? That is re-install it in a different folder, as suggested by @Ashoka.

Comment: i'm sorry but i don't know English that well can what is "re-deploy" and "isre-install" (i know what is install :) but not what is 'isre')

Comment: "isre-install" is actually "is re-install". Stupid mistake, I've corrected it. Try installing the Android SDK again. It's not a good sign that you can't open the SDK Manager.

Comment: LOL and i didn't get why even google-translate don't know what is ti :) i'm now downloading the adt again...

Comment: :-))) Yeah, those mistakes are not visible at first, if you don't use english that often :)

Comment: Thanks! The re-install did it (i don't know why, because i already tried to re-install) :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try installing the JDK outside Program Files? That is install it in a directory, which does not have any spaces in the path. For example install the JDK in the following directory and try again

```
c:\installs\java
```

Answer (score 0):

Make Sdk  update to repair the sdk bundle and try making some 
avds

Comment: How can i do it if i can't open the SDK Manager?

Comment: Uninstall it and re install it again

Answer (score -1):

Your JAVA_HOME might be configured wrongly. Trying changing the path to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\jre\bin`