# Could not find or load main class com.android.sdkmanager.Main

Tags: java, android, android-sdk-tools, android-sdk-2.3

I read [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4394584/android-sdk-install-problem?rq=1), [and these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6234403/sdk-manager-exe-doesnt-work-android?rq=1), [and these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17424923/android-sdk-not-working) issues about Android SDK installation troubles.

Nothing works for me.

Every time I get the error

```
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\tools>android
Error: Could not find or load main class com.android.sdkmanager.Main
```

when I try to start android.bat.

My environment:

```
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\tools>java -version
java version "1.7.0_71"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_71-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.71-b01, mixed mode)

JAVA_HOME=c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_71\jre\bin

PATH=c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_71\jre\bin\;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;...
```

I use latest android SDK version (on Dec 8, 2014) - installer_r23.0.2-windows.exe, tried to use latest JDK7 & JDK8 builds. Same error all the time.

How to fix this?

Comment: Try to not take the latest build, but some previous stable version instead.

Answer (score 11):

## Issue:

The JAR required in in the bat file is in path `%APP_HOME%\..\lib\sdkmanager-classpath.jar`,
but the file was extracted to `%APP_HOME%..\lib\_\sdkmanager-classpath.jar`, due to an issue in the unzip program used to unzip it.

## Solution:

So don't use the Windows' embedded unzip tool. Switch to another, like 7z.
The directory will then be referenced correctly, and you can run sdkmanager.bat without errors.

Comment: Do you have a source link detailing that the the unzip program used is the issue, or why one program causes this issue, while the other does not? *RE: "but caused by some unzip issue".*

Comment: @SherylHohman sorry I didn't find any detail link, only from some old programming experience, windows embed unzip tool will treat file or dir named dot, slash into underscore.

Answer (score 7):

A clean way to go about this is to follow the following steps:

- Go to `/path-to-android-sdk/`
- Delete the `Tools` directory
- Open Android Studio
- Open tools -> Sdk Manager
- Click on the `Sdk Tools` Tab
- Uncheck `Hide Obsolete Packages`
- Go into the Modal and check `Android Sdk Tools (Obsolete)`
- Click `Apply`
- Wait While it Downloads....
- When download is done,go back to `/path-to-android-sdk/`
- You should find your tools directory again
- Everything should work fine now.

**Note: What we simply did was delete and replace the old Tools which was corrupted or incompatible**

Comment: I also replaced the command-line tool folder.

Answer (score 2):

I think the latest version '6200805' has some issue, even I got the same problem.

Solution: Use the older SDK manager version, please find below links for the older version.

Windows no installer: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sdk-tools-windows-4333796.zip

MacOSX: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sdk-tools-darwin-4333796.zip

Linux: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sdk-tools-linux-4333796.zip

Comment: Hello Rayanni. Could you please provide link to the page containing links to previous versions instead of direct links to files?

Answer (score 0):

Look for `sdkmanager.jar`. This file should be located in the `...tools\lib` folder. According to the content of the executed `android.bat`:

```
...
set jar_path=lib\sdkmanager.jar;lib\swtmenubar.jar
...
```

In my case, I also had a /lib_cc folder which contained the missing files. The problem was fixed with backed up the origin `/lib` file to `/lib_1` and copy of `/lib_cc` to `/lib`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have all the required Android SDK packages installed too, these include SDK Platform 25, Android SDK Build-Tools 25.0.2 or later, Android Support Repository, Google Repository and any other SDKs that you may need.
OR
Try To Reinstall

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by opening sdkmanager.bat file
find this line

---

Change this line

`set CLASSPATH=%APP_HOME%\lib\/sdkmanager-classpath.jar`

---

To

`set CLASSPATH=%APP_HOME%\lib\_\/sdkmanager-classpath.jar`

---

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this is during the initial extraction of .zip file for version '6200805'.

Extract using **7zip** or any other extraction tool. 
The Windows standard "Extract All..." option create a folder with name "-" under the *.\tools\lib* path and places all jar files there causing the issue.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by setting the correct folder hierarchy.
which is **ANDROID_HOME>cmdline-tools>tools**

Copy the **tools** folder which contain all the files of command line tools into a folder named **cmdline-tools**. Then it will work.

The tools installed using sdkmanager (eg platform-tools) will be installed in the folder which contains the cmdline-tools folder, in my case **ANDROID_HOME** folder

Answer (score 0):

Downloading the latest SDK fixed it for me - Could not find or load main class com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli

Answer (score 0):

On Windows Server 2019, as of commandlinetools-win-6609375_latest.zip we were facing same issue.
We placed package inside "Program Files" i.e. "C:\Program Files\Android\cmdline-tools\tools\bin".

It seems this will not work if there is space in path. So we placed it in folder path without spaces i.e. "C:\Android\cmdline-tools\tools\bin" and it is working fine.

As explained in [Sdkmanager "Error: Could not find or load main class com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli" on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60727326/sdkmanager-error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-com-android-sdklib-tool-sdk)