# Sdkmanager "Error: Could not find or load main class com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli" on Windows

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, sdk, android-sdk-manager

I am trying to install Flutter without Android Studio and here is what I did:

- Installed Java 8
- Installed and Unzipped Flutter SDK to `C:\src`.
- Installed and Unzipped Android Command-line tools (sdkmanager) to `C:\Android`.
- Added the environment variables (ANDROID_HOME: C:\Android)

Now when I try to run `sdkmanager` to install Android SDK, I get this error:

`"Error: Could not find or load main class com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli"`

I have tried reinstalling Flutter sdk and the sdkmanager with no luck.

Here is Flutter Doctor's output:
[image: Flutter version: 1.12.13, Dart version: 2.7, Flutter can't find Android SDK]

sdkmanager error:
[image: "Error: Could not find or load main class com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli"]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. Download the SDK tools ZIP (Under Command Line Tools in https://developer.android.com/studio).
2. Unzip using **7zip**. Avoid using the default windows extractor - that doesn't do the extraction correctly.
3. After unzipping using 7zip, place the contents into the sdk folder (`C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\bin` and `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\lib`) and run `sdkmanager` on command prompt.

Comment: It seems that nowadays this needs to be in `cmdline-tools/latest` instead of just `tools`.

Answer (score 16):

Open the `sdkmanager.bat` in a text editor and add `echo %CLASSPATH%`  just below the `CLASSPATH=%APP_HOME%\...\sdkmanager-classpath.jar`. Then run `sdkmanager --help` which will echo the CLASSPATH of the required file. And check whether is it the valid path.

In my case, it was the wrong path,

[image]

It said my `sdkmanger-classpath.jar` is in `lib` folder. But it was not! It was actually inside the `lib/_` folder. So as the simple solution what I  did was copy the content in side `lib/_` folder to `lib`. Then it worked fine!

Comment: BIG ITEM here is using Windows to UNZIP the archive was the failure.  Using 7-zip properly has the files in their respective folders.  Good alternate find on the path though.

Answer (score 7):

On Windows Server 2019, using *commandlinetools-win-6609375_latest.zip*, we faced the same issue. We placed package inside *Program File* (i.e. *C:\Program Files\Android\cmdline-tools\tools\bin*).

It seems this will not work if there is space in the path. So we placed it in folder path without spaces (i.e. *C:\Android\cmdline-tools\tools\bin*) and it is working fine!

Comment: This was happening to me too. Instead of moving it to a different path, I edited a line in sdkmanager.bat, just putting quotes around the `toolsdir` argument. Like this: `set DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS=-Dcom.android.sdklib.toolsdir="%~dp0\.."`

Comment: Thank you! I had the same problem with a space in the path

Comment: @Jan After three hours this helped

Answer (score 4):

As @Chrishan wrote `Avoid using default windows extractor`.

You can use the PowerShell:

```bsh
Expand-Archive  commandlinetools....zip  C:\Android\Sdk
```

Answer (score 3):

It worked for me.
Make sure there exists no space in the path folders in the path to SDK.
example: `C:\Users\Anu Jadav\xyz\`

like above in username I had space, Initially, I was not able to execute flutter doctor --android-licenses.

After I renamed the username. Then it worked like a charm.
I renamed my username using  this [reference video](https://youtu.be/XASJTN8Sr1I)

.

Answer (score 3):

Go to android sdk folder.

Open cmdline-tools folder.

Then rename "latest" folder as "tools".

**Default name:**
(Path to sdk)\AndroidSDK\cmdline-tools\latest

**After rename:**
(Path to sdk)\AndroidSDK\cmdline-tools\tools

Then;
run `flutter doctor` command using terminal.

Comment: This answer help me solve my problem. I've moved the SDK from one path to another. Thanks @Lojith

Comment: After doing this, `flutter doctor` gives the same unfavourable output. Except now on running `flutter doctor --android-licenses` the error has changed to: "Android sdkmanager not found. Update to the latest Android SDK and ensure that the cmdline-tools are installed to resolve this."

Answer (score 1):

I fixed by adding '--sdkroot ' pointing to the root folder (i.e. parent of bin).
e.g. % ./bin/sdkamanager --sdkroot .

Comment: The truth is... I was giving Win10 a try but I didn't really like it, so I am back to Linux now hence can't try your answer. I am accepting tho 

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this issue by doing so many things.

1. Download Java 8.
2. Set EV to the Java 8 folder.
3. Download SDK in separate folder.
4. While setting EV of SDK make it sure there is no whitespace in the path.
5. Set path of the following in user variables:

   - Build-tools.
   - platform-tools.
   - platform
6. Now enter `flutter doctor --android-licenses`

   - press `y` multiple times and at last your licenses will be accepted.
7. Check whether your license accepted or not by using `flutter doctor`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly open android studio and from there open sdk manager and install required sdk tools then -

1. Make sure there exist no space in the path folders in the path to sdk.
2. Add ANDROID_SDK_ROOT variable to the Users variable with value as the path for sdk folder e.g. C:\users\xyz\android\sdk (there should be no space in these folder names).
3. Add this path to the path variable in the system variable.
4. Run flutter doctor in the command prompt.
5. Run flutter doctor --android-licenses.
6. Accept the licenses by entering 'y'.

--The setup should be done and just check by running flutter doctor.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by removing a space in my path where i had extracted the cmd tools.
My path was:

> C:\Cordova Tools\cmdline-tools

there was a space in folder name "Cordova Tools".
I removed the space and changed folder name like:

> C:\Cordova_Tools\cmdline-tools

And it worked just perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be due to the fact that your sdk installation failed severally before finally installing.
To check if that is the case, go the path C:\Users<username>\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk and if there are tools, tools-1, ...
The necessary files are installed in the last of this folder.
So, rename the supposed original folder - tools, to something else and change the name of the one in which the installation is done to tools.
This should solve the problem.

Comment: The question already has an accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

download jdk 11
and update ev **JAVA_HOME to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.17**