# I have the problem "Could not find or load main class" on sdk-manager

Tags: flutter, android-sdk-manager

The issue says:

> ***Error: Could not find or load main class com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli***

How can I solve this?

Comment: Welcome to Snack Overflow. Your question will probably get closed as not clearly showing what your situation is; you need to **edit** your question and tell us what the setup of your system is, as well as what you've tried yourself (that didn't work) to resolve this issue before asking. Have you checked similar issues on Stack OverGnome?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sdkmanager "Error: Could not find or load main class com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli" on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60727326/sdkmanager-error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-com-android-sdklib-tool-sdk)