# Cant run flutter doctor - - license

Tags: java, android, flutter, sdk, flutter-doctor

```
C:\Users\USER>flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):

[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.0.6, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.928], locale en-US)

[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    X Android license status unknown.

      Run flutter doctor --android-licenses to accept the SDK licenses.
      See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for more details.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web

[√] Android Studio

[√] VS Code (version 1.56.1)

[√] Connected device (2 available)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.

C:\Users\USER>flutter doctor --android-licenses

Error: Could not find or load main class J\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmdline-tools\latest\bin\\..
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: J\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmdline-tools\latest\bin\\//
```

EDIT 1:

I tried reinstalling sdk (after deleting files completely from appdata/android/sdk). it kinda worked but now new error is showing.:

```
C:\Users\USER>flutter doctor --android-licenses
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema
        at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule$SchemaModuleVersion.<init>(SchemaModule.java:156)
        at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule.<init>(SchemaModule.java:75)
        at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.<clinit>(AndroidSdkHandler.java:81)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:73)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:48)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
        ... 5 more
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sdkmanager "Error: Could not find or load main class com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli" on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60727326/sdkmanager-error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-com-android-sdklib-tool-sdk)

Comment: No, already tried that.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of searching and a lot of diff types of error ranging from environmental variable errors and java errors, i just uninstalled android studio, java and flutter files
deleted appdatas etc. and reinstalled it again now flutter doctors works fine.

i know this is not a good solution but someone could try this if all else fails.
thks

Answer (score 0):

*The crux of this issue seem to be with spaces in the Android SDK path*, e.g. if your user name on windows is "John Smith", it will fail to detect the android SDK. The solution is to move 'C:\Users\John Smith\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk' to a path with no spaces, e.g. 'C:\Android\Sdk'. Then run the following

```
flutter config --android-sdk "C:\Android\Sdk"
```

PS: for a related issue where it says "[!] Android Studio (not installed)", run the following to manually point it to the default Android Studio install location

```
flutter config --android-studio-dir "C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio"
```