# Buildozer Android : Could not find or load main class com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli

Tags: python, android, apk, cython, buildozer

I am super annoyed right now! I have spent countless hours trying to get this to work. I have a python file called main.py, and a spec called buildozer.spec

My python code:

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Label(text="Hello, Kivy!")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

My Spec file:

```
[app]

# Title of your application
title = My Application

# Package name
package.name = myapp

# Package domain (needed for android/ios packaging)
package.domain = org.test

# Source code where the main.py lives
source.dir = .

# Source files to include (let empty to include only main.py)
source.include_exts = 

# Application versioning
version = 0.1

# Application requirements
requirements = python3==3.10.8,kivy

# Android SDK path (use forward slashes)
android.sdk_path = C:/Users/judah/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk



log_level = 2
```

I don't understand why it's not working. Here is the result when I run: "buildozer android debug deploy run":

```
# Check configuration tokens
# Ensure build layout
# Create directory /mnt/c/users/judah/onedrive/desktop/other folders/coding/codingClass/rasberry pi/.buildozer
# Create directory /mnt/c/users/judah/onedrive/desktop/other folders/coding/codingClass/rasberry pi/bin
# Create directory /mnt/c/users/judah/onedrive/desktop/other folders/coding/codingClass/rasberry pi/.buildozer/applibs
# Create directory /mnt/c/users/judah/onedrive/desktop/other folders/coding/codingClass/rasberry pi/.buildozer/android/platform
# Create directory /mnt/c/users/judah/onedrive/desktop/other folders/coding/codingClass/rasberry pi/.buildozer/android/app
# Check configuration tokens
# Preparing build
# Check requirements for android
# Search for Git (git)
#  -> found at /usr/bin/git
# Search for Cython (cython)
#  -> found at /home/jstark09/.local/bin/cython
# Search for Java compiler (javac)
#  -> found at /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac
# Search for Java keytool (keytool)
#  -> found at /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/keytool
# Install platform
# Run ['git', 'clone', '-b', 'master', '--single-branch', 'https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android.git', 'python-for-android']
# Cwd /mnt/c/users/judah/onedrive/desktop/other folders/coding/codingClass/rasberry pi/.buildozer/android/platform
Cloning into 'python-for-android'...
Updating files: 100% (583/583), done.
# Run ['/usr/bin/python3', '-m', 'pip', 'install', '-q', '--user', 'appdirs', 'colorama>=0.3.3', 'jinja2', 'sh>=1.10, <2.0; sys_platform!="win32"', 'build', 'toml', 'packaging']
# Cwd None
# Apache ANT found at /home/jstark09/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4
# Android SDK is missing, downloading
# Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/commandlinetools-linux-6514223_latest.zip
# Unpacking Android SDK
# Run ['unzip', '-q', '/mnt/c/users/judah/onedrive/desktop/other folders/coding/codingClass/rasberry pi/C:/Users/judah/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/commandlinetools-linux-6514223_latest.zip']
# Cwd /mnt/c/users/judah/onedrive/desktop/other folders/coding/codingClass/rasberry pi/C:/Users/judah/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk
# Android SDK tools base installation done.
# Recommended android's NDK version by p4a is: 25b
# Android NDK found at /home/jstark09/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b
# Installing/updating SDK platform tools if necessary
# Run ['/mnt/c/users/judah/onedrive/desktop/other folders/coding/codingClass/rasberry pi/C:/Users/judah/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager', '--sdk_root=/mnt/c/users/judah/onedrive/desktop/other folders/coding/codingClass/rasberry pi/C:/Users/judah/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk', 'platform-tools']
# Cwd /mnt/c/users/judah/onedrive/desktop/other folders/coding/codingClass/rasberry pi/C:/Users/judah/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk
Error: Could not find or load main class folders.coding.codingClass.rasberry
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: folders.coding.codingClass.rasberry
# Command failed: ['/mnt/c/users/judah/onedrive/desktop/other folders/coding/codingClass/rasberry pi/C:/Users/judah/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager', '--sdk_root=/mnt/c/users/judah/onedrive/desktop/other folders/coding/codingClass/rasberry pi/C:/Users/judah/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk', 'platform-tools']
# ENVIRONMENT:
#     SHELL = '/bin/bash'
#     WSL2_GUI_APPS_ENABLED = '1'
#     WSL_DISTRO_NAME = 'Ubuntu'
#     NAME = 'JudahLaptop'
#     PWD = ('/mnt/c/users/judah/onedrive/desktop/other '
 'folders/coding/codingClass/rasberry pi')
#     LOGNAME = 'jstark09'
#     HOME = '/home/jstark09'
#     LANG = 'C.UTF-8'
#     WSL_INTEROP = '/run/WSL/370_interop'
#     LS_COLORS = 'rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.webp=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:'
#     WAYLAND_DISPLAY = 'wayland-0'
#     LESSCLOSE = '/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s'
#     TERM = 'xterm-256color'
#     LESSOPEN = '| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s'
#     USER = 'jstark09'
#     DISPLAY = ':0'
#     SHLVL = '1'
#     XDG_RUNTIME_DIR = '/run/user/1000/'
#     WSLENV = ''
#     XDG_DATA_DIRS = '/usr/local/share:/usr/share:/var/lib/snapd/desktop'
#     PATH = ('/home/jstark09/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/home/jstark09/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/lib/wsl/lib:/mnt/c/Program '
 'Files/Common Files/Oracle/Java/javapath:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Common '
 'Files/Oracle/Java/javapath:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/system32:/mnt/c/WINDOWS:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/OpenSSH/:/mnt/c/Program '
 'Files/Git/cmd:/mnt/c/Users/judah/AppData/Roaming/nvm:/mnt/c/Program '
 'Files/nodejs:/mnt/c/Users/judah/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310:/mnt/c/Users/judah/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/mnt/c/Users/judah/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft '
 'VS '
 'Code/bin:/mnt/c/Users/judah/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/Scripts:/mnt/c/Program '
 'Files/JetBrains/PyCharm Community Edition '
 '2022.3.1/bin:/mnt/c/Users/judah/AppData/Roaming/npm:/snap/bin:\\wsl.localhostUbuntuhomejstark09.localbin:/home/jstark09/.local/bin')
#     DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS = 'unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus'
#     HOSTTYPE = 'x86_64'
#     PULSE_SERVER = 'unix:/mnt/wslg/PulseServer'
#     OLDPWD = '/home/jstark09'
#     _ = '/home/jstark09/.local/bin/buildozer'
#
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

I have installed:
pip
python
java sdk
cython
android sdk
and I am using **Ubuntu**
Can someone **PLEASE** help me!?!

I would really appreciate it!

Comment: ```Error: Could not find or load main class folders.coding.codingClass.rasberry```  Might this help?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093928/what-does-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-mean

Comment: You are using a path that 1. is in your OneDrive and 2. has spaces. Both can be problematic, so when using a path I would recommend to you use short paths not synced anywhere and that don't contain spaces or other special characters.

Comment: see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60727326/sdkmanager-error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-com-android-sdklib-tool-sdk) for the same error message in windows