# Cordova fails to find ANDROID_HOME environment variable

Tags: android, bash, macos, cordova, avd-manager

I looked all over Google and Stack Overflow for an answer, but I couldn't find the right one for me. I am learning Cordova and I'm trying to run the android emulator through terminal, and when I run 'sudo cordova emulate android' I get this message:

''Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable. Try setting it manually.
Detected 'avdmanager' command at /Users/username/Library/Android/sdk/cmdline-tools/latest/bin but no 'tools/bin' directory found near.
Try reinstall Android SDK or update your PATH to include valid path to SDK/tools/bin directory.''

But I set the variables in the ~./bash_profile file and it looks like this:

```
export ANDROID_HOME="/Users/username/Library/Android/sdk"

export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=$ANDROID_HOME

export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/cmdline-tools/latest/bin:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools

export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin

export PATH="$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/build-tools/30.0.0-rc2"
```

I am using a MacOS Mojave, does anyone know what the issue is? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting ANDROID\_HOME enviromental variable on Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19986214/setting-android-home-enviromental-variable-on-mac-os-x)

Comment: Have you ever seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19986214/setting-android-home-enviromental-variable-on-mac-os-x)

Comment: @RezaDehnavi thanks for the help, it still doesn't work, I'll try it on Windows.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, in the latest version of Android Studio, the old SDK tools (under `/tools`, which Cordova seems to expect) are already considered obsolete. There is a solution documented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60944534/1460448) on how to install the old version of SDK tools.

- Open Android Studio
- Open Tools -> Sdk Manager
- Click on the `Sdk Tools` Tab
- Uncheck `Hide Obsolete Packages`
- Check `Android Sdk Tools (Obsolete)`
- Click `Apply`

This should download the old SDK tools under the correct folder.

However, I think Cordova also needs to keep up with the newest Android development tools. There's another change I needed to make after this:

I had to delete the `tools/emulator` and `tools/emulator-check` binaries, and add `$ANDROID_HOME/emulator` to my `$PATH`, since the current emulator binary lives under `emulator/emulator` instead of `path/emulator`. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26483370/android-emulator-error-message-panic-missing-emulator-engine-program-for-x86).

Then I was finally able to launch the app directly via Cordova.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR : don't set `ANDROID_HOME` at all.

I encountered this error in 2023, and downgrading the JDK or SDK tools would give me a whole bunch of other issues with gradle etc.

cordova seemed to need `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` to be set, but `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` clashed with `ANDROID_HOME` and resulted in the above error.

I've changed my .zshrc to completely unset `ANDROID_HOME`; note that this is backwards since `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` [is deprecated in favour of `ANDROID_HOME`](https://developer.android.com/tools/variables#envar).

My `.zshrc` file now has the following :

```bash
# cordova-android was complaining it couldn't find the tools bin, for now I have to use ...
#  ... ANDROID_SDK_ROOT and ensure ANDROID_HOME is not set
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT="/Users/me/Library/Android/sdk"
export PATH="${PATH}:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/cmdline-tools/latest/bin:${ANDROID_SDK_ROOT}/platform-tools:${ANDROID_SDK_ROOT}/emulator:${ANDROID_SDK_ROOT}/tools/bin:${ANDROID_SDK_ROOT}/tools"
unset ANDROID_HOME
```